# Date subscription get triggered when other part of the state change in ngrx

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a `start` and `end` property which stores a date in my `state`.Anytime other part of the state get changed my `subscription` for `start` and `end` date get triggered.

this is my subscription

```
this.subs.sink = this.store
      .select(fromTransactionReducer.selectStartAndEndDate)
      .subscribe((date) => {
        console.log("range", date);
        this.range.setValue({
          start: date.start,
          end: date.end,
        });
      });
```

this is the selector

```
export const selectStartAndEndDate = createSelector(
  selectTransactionState,
  (state) => ({ start: state.start, end: state.end })
);
```

this is the dateRange reducer

```
  on(transactionActions.UpdateDateRange, (state, { start, end }) => ({
    ...state,
    start,
    end,
  })),
```

this is the date range action

```
export const UpdateDateRange = createAction(
  "[Transaction Page] Update Date Range",
  props<{ start: Date; end: Date }>()
);
```

this is my state

```
export interface State {
  transaction: Transaction[];
  cursors: Cursor;
  totalTransactions: number;
  loading: boolean;
  errorMessage: string;
  formErrorMessage: string;
  items_per_page: number;
  pageSizeOptions: number[];
  pageIndex: number;
  searchKey: string;
  formMessage: string;
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
  trans_type: string;
  base_type: string;
}
export const initialState: State = {
  transaction: [],
  cursors: {
    after: "",
    before: "",
    hasNext: false,
    hasPrevious: false,
  },
  totalTransactions: 0,
  loading: false,
  errorMessage: null,
  formErrorMessage: null,
  items_per_page: 5,
  pageSizeOptions: [2, 3, 5, 10, 15],
  pageIndex: 0,
  searchKey: "",
  formMessage: "",
  start: null,
  end: null,
  trans_type: null,
  base_type: null,
};
```

Anytime i dispatch a different `action` for example `this.store.dispatch(transactionActions.ResetPageIndex());`, my `subscription` for the date get triggered.

***why is that ?***

In my reducer i only update `start` and `end` date when `UpdateDateRange` action is dispatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ngrx `select` operator utilizes the rxjs `distinctUntilChanged` operator to ensure that a selector only emits if its result has changed. Refer to the source code here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/a6fe92df3134b7a589a2e95abe0aea183b411f03/modules/store/src/store.ts#L249

By default `distinctUntilChanged` uses an equality comparer (refer to https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) and note *'object references must match!'*

Now to your `selectStartAndEndDate` selector - it returns an **object**.

Furthermore, it returns a **new instance** of an object each time it executes. Because of this, the comparison in `distinctUntilChanged` always fails so the selector always emits.

How to resolve it:

```
// returned date will be considered equal next time so selector won't fire
export const selectStartDate = createSelector(
  selectTransactionState,
  (state) => state.start
);

// same here
export const selectEndDate = createSelector(
  selectTransactionState,
  (state) => state.end
);

// as input selectors didn't change, this won't fire either
export const selectStartAndEndDate = createSelector(
  selectStartDate,
  selectEndDate ,
  (start, end) => ({ start, end })
);
```

Stackblitz: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-ngrx-selector-emit-1zxg1?file=/src/app/store/selectors.ts

Comment: I added `console.log()` to all the other `subscriptions` and i noticed that the other subscriptions didnt get triggered when another part of the state change.Only the `start` and `end` date is getting triggered when other other part of the state change for example when i dispatched  `this.store.dispatch(transactionActions.ResetPageIndex());` which reset only the `pageIndex` property, my subscription for the date get triggered

Comment: I am also using angular for my application

Comment: What does the `on` handler look like for `ResetPageIndex`?

Comment: ` on(transactionActions.ResetPageIndex, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    pageIndex: 0,
  }))`

Comment: what do you think is causing the problem?.

Comment: see above, new answer - sorry the original one was misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the correct explanation and solution. Although i could have move on with my code since it not an error, but something was drawing me back to try and understand what is really happenning and why .Thanks for clarifying that

Comment: No problem, was useful for me too.